# Как заменить prev/next из owl carousel на стрелки из font-awesome?

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel

Собственно вопрос. Если включить навигацию там кнопки prev/next. Как заменить на иконки из font awesome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться параметром в функции и передать нужный ՝HTML՝ или просто текст, например։

```
$(".slide").owlCarousel({
     items : 6,
     loop  : true,
     margin : 10,
     nav    : true,
     navText : ["<i class='fa fa-chevron-left'></i>","<i class='fa fa-chevron-right'></i>"]
   });
```

и всё..

Comment: Вы прямо чудеса телепатии проявляете. ))

Comment: @NickVolynkin, чем я заслужил такой  "комплимент" ? ))

Comment: Для меня вопрос звучит почти как бессвязный лепет. Однако вы его поняли и даже дали подходящий ответ. Может, отредактируете вопрос, чтобы и другим было понятно?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, эта "телепатия" назвается Team Lead :)  в повседневности приходится часто использовать "неземные способности"  ))

Comment: Ясно. :) У меня с Git такое бывает — человек описывает как бил в бубен и плевал через плечо, но по этому в принципе можно угадать, в чем корень проблемы.